# Iterating Through Specific Key in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have exported user activity that covers a period of dates. I am trying to pull the number of occurrences of a specific user activity across these dates.

I have verified that
    `print(data['response'][0]['data']['2019-07-06']['Product']['Daily Unique Users'])` returns the desired value. But there are a number of dates in this data and I don't want to have add a line for each one. Here's what I've tried:

````
with open('file.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for x in data:
        print(data['response'][0]['data'][x]['Product']['Daily Unique Users'])``` 

---
KeyError: 'response'
````

Comment: Can you add json file structure ?

Answer (score 2):

your for loop:

> for x in data:

will iterate based on the outer-most key in your dictionary data.

You should instead replace this by

> for x in data['response'][0]['data']:

Answer (score 0):

I will add an answer to further complement the other one. If you wish to iterate through every value for a certain key in a given dictionary and a keep certain part of it, then you need to add the rest of the keys/indexes of a list. Also, to save it somewhere, you can either create a list or a dictionary so you can ensure the information is stored somewhere:

```
info_to_be_stored = {'daily_unique_users':[]} # Initiate a dictionary with a list of the data you want.  
with open('file.json') as json_file:
     data = json.load(json_file)
     for x in data['response'][0]['data']:
            information = data['response'][0]['data'][x]['Product']['Daily Unique Users']) 
            print(information) #to visualize it
            info_to_be_stored['daily_unique_users'].append(information) #to store it in your dictionary
```

Please let me know if it works!